# Find how close is object to boundary

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm working on a Matlab script where I have a bunch of objects (particles) within another bigger object (channel or a tube). I can get the centroids of participles and boundaries of the bigger object (stored in a matrix).
I need to figure out if the particle is in the center or the boundary of the tube. The tube has an irregular shape (think sin like figure). I couldn't find a function that can do that within Image Processing library.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using diff() and just finding out how far the particle(x,y) is from the center or boundary(x,y)?

Comment: I haven't, but how would that work? My boundaries is just a set of x, y coordinates stored in a matrix. How will I know which boundary points I use for a specific particle (x, y)?

Comment: It may be useful to provide some code to clarify your question, see [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can either use some function that tells you if a point is inside a polygon, like

https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html

Or you fill the boundary polygon with a given value, then add another value to each particle coordinate. Now every point with a value of that sum is inside the large object.

Of course you can also use some boolean logic. Large object and particles are true, background is false. Then AND link both matrices/images to get any particles inside the object.

Answer (score 0):

if the boundary of the tube is a polygon you can calculate it's centroid using the formula from:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_a_polygon

Than iterate over all the particles and calculate the euclidean distance between the particle and the centroid of the tube and if it is in close enough you know the particle is in the center.